# Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker (eonasdan) - How to quickly select year? (for birthdays)

Tags: select, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Is it possible in [eonasdan's bootstrap 3 datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to change the `dayViewHeaderFormat` to show decades or a drop-down menu to choose a year quickly?

Because when someone wants to insert their birthday, it might take a lot of clicks to select the correct year and date. Is there an option to quickly select the correct year? If so, how would this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the [**`viewMode`** function](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#viewmode). From the documentation:

> **viewMode(newViewMode)**
>
> Takes a string. Valid values are '*days*', '*months*', '*years*' and '*decades*'

For example:

```
$('#birthday_years').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Do of MMMM, YYYY',
    defaultDate: new Date(1990, 0, 1, 00, 01),
    viewMode: 'years',
});
```

Here, I've initialised the `defaultDate` to 1990. You can, of course, change this or use  a `placeholder` to display a text in the input field. Like so:  `<input ... ... placeholder="Pick your birthday" />`.
I've also formatted the date. You can change the date format [with these options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Demonstration of the final result:

[image]

## [> GO TO DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9bks3m42/)

Comment: @ElenaEp You're welcome. On StackOverflow it is customary to consider accepting/upvoting my post if it answers your question (by clicking on the 'accept' button). Good luck with your project.

Comment: how select only year and not show months and days ?

Comment: @nim `viewMode: 'years'` and `minViewMode: 'years'`. See [this link](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/624).